# Validate form A's data by usuing form B's data

Tags: python, django, forms

So I have these two forms. I would like to be able to access the data in form env_form when I am checking add_uRG for my other form. Is it possible to do this? My env form is a very common form through out my app so I would like to keep it separate instead of including it on every form.

```
class env_form(forms.Form):
            env = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ENV, required=True)

    class add_uRG(forms.Form):
            user = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
            group = forms.CharField(required=True)
            role = forms.CharField(required=True)

            def clean_user(self):
                    post_user = self.cleaned_data['user']
                    post_env = self.cleaned_data['env']
                    c = User.objects.filter(user__contains=post_user, env__contains=post_env ).count()
                    if (c == 0):
                         raise forms.ValidationError(u"User Not Found.")
                    else:
                         user_info = User.objects.filter(user__contains=post_user).values('password').distinct().count()
                         user_env = User.objects.filter(user__contains=post_user).values('env').distinct().count()
                         if not (user_env == user_info):
                            raise forms.ValidationError(u'User is using same password')
                    return(post_user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think that form inheritance could be used here.

```
class env_form(forms.Form):
    env = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ENV, required=True)

class add_uRG(env_form):
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = forms.CharField(required=True)
    role = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def clean_user(self):
        post_user = self.cleaned_data['user']
        post_env = self.cleaned_data['env']
        c = User.objects.filter(user__contains=post_user, env__contains=post_env ).count()
        if (c == 0):
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"User Not Found.")
        else:
            user_info = User.objects.filter(user__contains=post_user).values('password').distinct().count()
            user_env = User.objects.filter(user__contains=post_user).values('env').distinct().count()
            if not (user_env == user_info):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'User is using same password')
        return(post_user)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(env_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class SomeOtherForm(env_form):
    some_field = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(env_form, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: hmm this does not seem to work for me. I try this method but it does not pull into my clean_user

Comment: Thanks I got yours to work. Turns out my form was messed up but once I got it to work yours worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a property on your add_uRG form after you validate the env_form, or you could pass the value to the add_uRG form as a parameter.

```
#forms.py
class AdduRGForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdduRGForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.env = None

#my_view.py
def my_view(request):
    env_form = env_form(request.POST or None)

    if request.POST:
        if env_form.is_valid():
            add_uRG_form = AdduRGForm(request.POST or None)
            add_uRG_form.env = env_form.cleaned_data.get('env')
            if add_uRG_form.is_valid():
                #do something else
    return render_to_response('template.html',
        {'env_form' : env_form, 'add_uRG_form' : add_uRG_form})
```

I'm not exactly sure of your workflow, so if these forms don't exist in the same view, like if you're processing the env_form first, and then going to another view and needing the value someone previously selected, you could pass in the request to env_form, and set the selection in session, which you could pick up again in the second form using the method I outlined.

Comment: I added the __init__ but not sure if it is working or not. Once I try to validate my form it just returns me the form and doesnt do the code in my #do something else. I tried to do a print of self.env in my clean_user(self): def but that didnt work

Comment: I made a minor change to your pastebin code in the view: http://pastebin.com/HbARraEQ

Comment: yea I forgot to make that change but it still did not work for me. But I did figure out my form wasn't being processed right. But even with your change it still says can not process queue as None. So its still not getting the env from the first form.

Comment: Hmm. Without actually setting up a project and working through this, it's kind of hard to determine why the env value wouldn't be in the cleaned data of the first form, but that's where I would be looking next. I've used the pattern of setting a property on a form and then populating it from another form many times, so I'm pretty confident that will work as advertised.

Comment: yea I see it in the args when they are getting passed to __init__ (<QueryDict: {u'role': [u'role-c'], u'group': [u'group-b'], u'user': [u'user-a'], u'env': [u'dev']}>,) but self.env=None just stays as none.